# using "@2x" in static google map URL

Tags: google-maps-markers, google-maps-static-api, retina

I am trying to create a custom static map with google static map api, using a custom marker.  the marker ends with "@2x.png". It seems google's api does not like this? It does work if I use the regular version that just ends in ".png".

Has anyone encountered this issue?

Edit:
It appears that the issue here may be that there is an icon dimension restriction.

from: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/staticmaps/#CustomIcons

> Icons are limited to sizes of 4096 pixels (64x64 for square images)

the image i was trying to use for the 2x scale was 78x98.

Answer (score 3):

Well in fact, it works when you activate the scale:2 mode. In your url, you have to check if this is present:

```
http://..../staticmap?&scale=2&markers=scale:2|icon:http://...../...@2x.png|lat,lon
```

It works pretty good on HD screens.
With these arguments, you image file can be up to 128x128.

Comment: I believe the issue i had was that while it did do a 2x scale of the map, it didn't scale the @2x image down.